# Why does a Servlet's doGet()-method have the response as parameter instead of return value?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I never questioned this before, but why

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException{}
```

instead of

```
public HttpServletResponse doGet(HttpServletRequest request)
    throws ServletException, IOException{}
```

?

Wouldn't the second version make semantically more sense?

Comment: Perhaps the response can be sent asynchronously piecemeal fashion in a seperate thread, rather than having to wait for all processing of the doGet to finish. Can't say I'm sure about that though.

Comment: How did you intend to create it? Why would you not just use the container-created one?

Comment: @BalusC I do not intend to create a Servlet. I just stumbled across some Servlet-code today and this question came to my mind.

Comment: I mean, how do you intend to create an instance of `HttpServletResponse`?

Comment: @BalusC I did not give further thinking to that. As [Orange Dog stated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20141873/1505606) this is quite complicated which I believe. I am not sure if it makes much sense to go deeper into this. Mainly I just wanted to know WHY a typical `doGet()`-method is build up like the way it is, instead of receiving the request as parameter, processing it and returning the response, which I would consider to make semantically more sense. But [Orange Dog's explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20141873/1505606) is comprehensible. What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpServletResponse` is a rather complicated class, requiring you to know about connection sockets and such. If you had to return one, most of the code would be the same boilerplate to construct it. Instead the servlet container does this work for you, giving you a ready-to-use object with a variety of useful working methods.

Now the next question is why did they decide to make `HttpServletResponse` a complicated object and not just have you return a simple POJO. Well for one, that architecture would not allow you do do any streaming responses where you start writing before you have all the data.